# Select all divs that contains a certain string in class name

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors

I am trying to get the list of all divs where class name contains `bp-table-cell` as a substring.

This returns divs that have class name exactly `bp-table-cell`

```
document.getElementsByClassName('bp-table-cell')
```

I found this which solves using jquery and need to solve without using jquery

```
$("div:regex(class, .*bp-table-cell.*)")
```

Comment: Please see the linked duplicate for the answer, essentially though the version of the answer in the linked duplicate for your specific case will be: `document.querySelectorAll('*[class*="bp-table-cell"]')`. In fact, jQuery inspired `document.querySelector` and as a result there are many overlapping features with regards to selectors.

Comment: @TravisJ Thanks for this. I still need next thing to know, Is it possible to make the above regex to give different two substrings? For example, The div whose class name must contain both `bp-table-cell` and `bp-table-cell-col-0` but they don't come together.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('.bp-table-cell-col-0[class*="bp-table-cell"]')`